# Transfer a database to SQL Server 2008 from SQL Server 2008 Express

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-express

Anyone know the generic practices transfer the database to SQL Server 2008 from SQL Server 2008 Express (I'm not sure it is r2), when I try to attach the `.mdf` file from Express, there is an error message.

> *the database cannot be opened because it is version 661. This server supports version 655 and earlier. A downgrade path is not
>   supported.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the message is clear: the file you're trying to attach from Express is from a **newer version** of SQL Server

So it appears that you indeed have SQL Server **2008 R2** Express, and you **cannot** attach this to a SQL Server **2008** instance. There's no way, no hack, no workaround, no trick, or no third-party tool to achieve this - it just cannot be done - period.

So you either need to upgrade your main instance to SQL Server **2008 R2**, too - or you need to find another way (like scripting out the structure and/or data into `.SQL` files) to move your changes from one instance to the other - or use a third-party tool like [Red-Gate SQL Compare](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) to synchronize the changes between the two instances.